# Characteristic cycle of theta divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, d-modules

Let $A/\mathbb{C}$ be an abelian variety with $\dim A=n$ and $H\subset A$ be an irreducible closed hypersurface, which as a divisor defines a principal polarization of $A$. We call $H$ a theta divisor of $A$. Let $i:H\to A$ be the closed immersion, $U$ be the smooth locus of $H$ and $j:U\to H$ the open immersion. Then the minimal extension $i_*j_{!*}(\mathbb{C}_U)[n-1]\in Perv(A)$ is a perverse sheaf on $A$. Then what is the characteristic cycle of it?

Comment: Could you remind me what is the characteristic cycle of minimal extension of $\mathbb C_{U}$, when $U=X\setminus Y$ and $Y$ is smooth in $X$?